# How to customize DevExtreme datagrid confirm message

Tags: jquery, html, devextreme, dx-data-grid

Is there any way to change 'yes' and 'no' text buttons in delete modal confirmation in modal?

I have tried this and change my message but i can not change yes and no button text

```
editing: {
            mode: "form",
            allowUpdating: true,
            allowDeleting: true,
            allowAdding: true,
            texts: {
                deleteRow: "delete",
                editRow: "edit",
                saveRowChanges: "save",
                cancelRowChanges: "cancele",
                confirmDeleteMessage: "are you sure?"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

To customize button text inside a confirmation dialog you can use the [localization.loadMessages()](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/Common/utils/localization/#loadMessages) method. The usage is quite simple:

```
DevExpress.localization.loadMessages({
    en: { "Yes": "Remove it!", "No": "Don't remove it!" }
});
```

This [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWwdRd) demonstrates it in action.

Comment: yes it is the answer . thank you. after this issue It occurred to me that use globlization files. I Link My file (dx.all.ru.js) but the message confirm is still ye and no .
in this way it is better i think ,yes? and could you plz tell me why i can not use (dx.all.ru.js)?

Comment: It looks like you did't use the `DevExpress.localization.locale("ru")` method. Updated sample - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWzXpY

Answer (score 0):

Sergey's answer should be marked as correct but here's an alternative brute force solution just for fun:

```
$('.dx-link-delete').on('click',
     function(){setTimeout(
         function(){
             var btns = $('.dx-popup-normal').find('.dx-button-text');
             btns.last().text('No thanks');
             btns.first().text('Yes please');
         },0);
     }
);
```